# Painting canvas and System.out.println() not working

Tags: java, swing, canvas, println

I have `JFrame` with a start button, which triggers the calculation of a [Julia Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julia_set). 
The code that is executed when the start button is clicked is as follows:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent aActionEvent) 
{
    String strCmd = aActionEvent.getActionCommand();

    if (strCmd.equals("Start")) 
    {
        m_cCanvas.init();
        m_cSMsg = "c = " + Double.toString(m_dReal) + " + " + "j*" + Double.toString(m_dImag);
        m_bRunning = true;
        this.handleCalculation();
    }
    else if (aActionEvent.getSource() == m_cTReal)
```

Which used to work fine, except that the application could not be closed anymore. So I tried to use `m_bRunning` in a separate method so that `actionPerformed()` isn't blocked all the time to see if that would help, and then set `m_bRunning = false` in the method `stop()` which is called when the window is closed:

```
public void run()
{
    if(m_bRunning)
    {
        this.handleCalculation();
    }
}
```

The method `run()` is called from the main class in a `while(true)` loop.

Yet unfortunately, neither did that solve the problem, nor do I now have any output to the canvas or any debug traces with `System.out.println()`. Could anyone point me in the right direction on this?

**EDIT:**

Here are the whole files:

```
// cMain.java
package juliaSet;

import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.Dimension;

public class cMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int windowWidth = 1000;//(int)screenSize.getWidth() - 200;
        int windowHeight = 800;//(int)screenSize.getHeight() - 50;
        int plotWidth = 400;//(int)screenSize.getWidth() - 600;
        int plotHeight = 400;//(int)screenSize.getHeight() - 150;

        JuliaSet cJuliaSet = new JuliaSet("Julia Set", windowWidth, windowHeight, plotWidth, plotHeight);       
        cJuliaSet.setVisible(true);     
        while(true)
        {  
            cJuliaSet.run();
        }
    }

}


// JuliaSet.java
package juliaSet;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Random;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.ref.*;

public class JuliaSet extends JFrame implements ActionListener 
{
    private JButton m_cBStart;
    private JTextField m_cTReal;
    private JTextField m_cTImag;
    private JTextField m_cTDivergThresh;
    private JLabel m_cLReal;
    private JLabel m_cLImag;
    private JLabel m_cLDivergThresh;
    private int m_iDivergThresh = 10;
    private String m_cMsgDivThresh = "Divergence threshold = " + m_iDivergThresh;
    private JuliaCanvas m_cCanvas;
    private int m_iPlotWidth; // number of cells
    private int m_iPlotHeight; // number of cells
    private Boolean m_bRunning = false;
    private double m_dReal = 0.3;
    private double m_dImag = -0.5;
    private String m_cSMsg = "c = " + Double.toString(m_dReal) + " + " + "j*" + Double.toString(m_dImag);
    private String m_cMsgIter = "x = 0, y = 0";
    private Complex m_cCoordPlane[][];
    private double m_dAbsSqValues[][];
    private int m_iIterations[][];
    private Complex m_cSummand;
    private BufferedImage m_cBackGroundImage = null;
    private FileWriter m_cFileWriter;
    private BufferedWriter m_cBufferedWriter;
    private String m_sFileName = "log.txt";
    private Boolean m_bWriteLog = false;

    private static final double PLOTMAX = 2.0; // we'll have symmetric axes
                                                // ((0,0) at the centre of the
                                                // plot
    private static final int MAXITER = 0xff;

    JuliaSet(String aTitle, int aFrameWidth, int aFrameHeight, int aPlotWidth, int aPlotHeight) 
    {
        super(aTitle);
        this.setSize(aFrameWidth, aFrameHeight);
        m_iPlotWidth = aPlotWidth;
        m_iPlotHeight = aPlotHeight;
        m_cSummand = new Complex(m_dReal, m_dImag);

        m_cBackGroundImage = new BufferedImage(aFrameWidth, aFrameHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                stop();
                super.windowClosing(e);
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        GridBagLayout cLayout = new GridBagLayout();
        GridBagConstraints cConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();

        this.setLayout(cLayout);
        m_cCanvas = new JuliaCanvas(m_iPlotWidth, m_iPlotHeight);
        m_cCanvas.setSize(m_iPlotWidth, m_iPlotHeight);

        m_cBStart = new JButton("Start");
        m_cBStart.addActionListener(this);
        m_cTReal = new JTextField(5);
        m_cTReal.addActionListener(this);
        m_cTImag = new JTextField(5);
        m_cTImag.addActionListener(this);
        m_cTDivergThresh = new JTextField(5);
        m_cTDivergThresh.addActionListener(this);
        m_cLReal = new JLabel("Re(c):");
        m_cLImag = new JLabel("Im(c):");
        m_cLDivergThresh = new JLabel("Divergence Threshold:");

        cConstraints.insets.top = 3;
        cConstraints.insets.bottom = 3;
        cConstraints.insets.right = 3;
        cConstraints.insets.left = 3;

        // cCanvas
        cConstraints.gridx = 0;
        cConstraints.gridy = 0;
        cLayout.setConstraints(m_cCanvas, cConstraints);
        this.add(m_cCanvas);

        // m_cLReal
        cConstraints.gridx = 0;
        cConstraints.gridy = 1;
        cLayout.setConstraints(m_cLReal, cConstraints);
        this.add(m_cLReal);

        // m_cTReal
        cConstraints.gridx = 1;
        cConstraints.gridy = 1;
        cLayout.setConstraints(m_cTReal, cConstraints);
        this.add(m_cTReal);

        // m_cLImag
        cConstraints.gridx = 0;
        cConstraints.gridy = 2;
        cLayout.setConstraints(m_cLImag, cConstraints);
        this.add(m_cLImag);

        // m_cTImag
        cConstraints.gridx = 1;
        cConstraints.gridy = 2;
        cLayout.setConstraints(m_cTImag, cConstraints);
        this.add(m_cTImag);

        // m_cLDivergThresh
        cConstraints.gridx = 0;
        cConstraints.gridy = 3;
        cLayout.setConstraints(m_cLDivergThresh, cConstraints);
        this.add(m_cLDivergThresh);

        // m_cTDivergThresh
        cConstraints.gridx = 1;
        cConstraints.gridy = 3;
        cLayout.setConstraints(m_cTDivergThresh, cConstraints);
        this.add(m_cTDivergThresh);

        // m_cBStart
        cConstraints.gridx = 0;
        cConstraints.gridy = 4;
        cLayout.setConstraints(m_cBStart, cConstraints);
        this.add(m_cBStart);
        if (m_bWriteLog) 
        {
            try 
            {
                m_cFileWriter = new FileWriter(m_sFileName, false);
                m_cBufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(m_cFileWriter);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Error opening file '" + m_sFileName + "'");
            }
        }

        this.repaint();

        this.transformCoordinates();
    }

    public synchronized void stop() 
    {
        if (m_bRunning) 
        {
            m_bRunning = false;
            boolean bRetry = true;
        }
        if (m_bWriteLog) 
        {
            try {
                m_cBufferedWriter.close();
                m_cFileWriter.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Error closing file '" + m_sFileName + "'");
            }
        }
    }
    public void collectGarbage() 
    {
        Object cObj = new Object();
        WeakReference ref = new WeakReference<Object>(cObj);
        cObj = null;
        while(ref.get() != null) {
            System.gc();
        }
    }

    public void setSummand(Complex aSummand) 
    {
        m_cSummand.setIm(aSummand.getIm());
        m_dImag = aSummand.getIm();
        m_cSummand.setRe(aSummand.getRe());
        m_dReal = aSummand.getRe();
        m_cSMsg = "c = " + Double.toString(m_dReal) + " + " + "j*" + Double.toString(m_dImag);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics aGraphics) 
    {
        Graphics cScreenGraphics = aGraphics;
        // render on background image
        aGraphics = m_cBackGroundImage.getGraphics();

        this.paintComponents(aGraphics);
        // drawString() calls are debug code only....
        aGraphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        aGraphics.drawString(m_cSMsg, 10, 450);
        aGraphics.drawString(m_cMsgIter, 10, 465);
        aGraphics.drawString(m_cMsgDivThresh, 10, 480);

        // rendering is done, draw background image to on screen graphics
        cScreenGraphics.drawImage(m_cBackGroundImage, 0, 0, null);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent aActionEvent) 
    {
        String strCmd = aActionEvent.getActionCommand();

        if (strCmd.equals("Start")) 
        {
            m_cCanvas.init();
            m_cSMsg = "c = " + Double.toString(m_dReal) + " + " + "j*" + Double.toString(m_dImag);
            m_bRunning = true;
        } 
        else if (aActionEvent.getSource() == m_cTReal) 
        {
            m_dReal = Double.parseDouble(m_cTReal.getText());
            m_cSMsg = "c = " + Double.toString(m_dReal) + " + " + "j*" + Double.toString(m_dImag);
            m_cSummand.setRe(m_dReal);
        } 
        else if (aActionEvent.getSource() == m_cTImag) 
        {
            m_dImag = Double.parseDouble(m_cTImag.getText());
            m_cSMsg = "c = " + Double.toString(m_dReal) + " + " + "j*" + Double.toString(m_dImag);
            m_cSummand.setIm(m_dImag);
        } 
        else if (aActionEvent.getSource() == m_cTDivergThresh) 
        {
            m_iDivergThresh = Integer.parseInt(m_cTDivergThresh.getText());
            m_cMsgDivThresh = "Divergence threshold = " + m_iDivergThresh;
        }

        this.update(this.getGraphics());
    }

    public void transformCoordinates() 
    {
        double dCanvasHeight = (double) m_cCanvas.getHeight();
        double dCanvasWidth = (double) m_cCanvas.getWidth();
        // init matrix with same amount of elements as pixels in canvas
        m_cCoordPlane = new Complex[(int) dCanvasHeight][(int) dCanvasWidth];
        double iPlotRange = 2 * PLOTMAX;

        for (int i = 0; i < dCanvasHeight; i++) 
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < dCanvasWidth; j++) 
            {

                m_cCoordPlane[i][j] = new Complex((i - (dCanvasWidth / 2)) * iPlotRange / dCanvasWidth,
                        (j - (dCanvasHeight / 2)) * iPlotRange / dCanvasHeight);
            }
        }

    }

    public void calcAbsSqValues() 
    {
        int iCanvasHeight = m_cCanvas.getHeight();
        int iCanvasWidth = m_cCanvas.getWidth();
        // init matrix with same amount of elements as pixels in canvas
        m_dAbsSqValues = new double[iCanvasHeight][iCanvasWidth];
        m_iIterations = new int[iCanvasHeight][iCanvasWidth];
        Complex cSum = new Complex();

        if (m_bWriteLog) {
            try 
            {
                m_cBufferedWriter.write("m_iIterations[][] =");
                m_cBufferedWriter.newLine();
            } 
            catch (IOException ex) 
            {
                System.out.println("Error opening file '" + m_sFileName + "'");
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < iCanvasHeight; i++) 
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < iCanvasWidth; j++) 
            {
                cSum.setRe(m_cCoordPlane[i][j].getRe());
                cSum.setIm(m_cCoordPlane[i][j].getIm());
                m_iIterations[i][j] = 0;
                do 
                {
                    m_iIterations[i][j]++;
                    cSum.square();
                    cSum.add(m_cSummand);
                    m_dAbsSqValues[i][j] = cSum.getAbsSq();
                } while ((m_iIterations[i][j] < MAXITER) && (m_dAbsSqValues[i][j] < m_iDivergThresh));
                this.calcColour(i, j, m_iIterations[i][j]);
                m_cMsgIter = "x = " + i + " , y = " + j;

                 if(m_bWriteLog)
                 {
                    System.out.println(m_cMsgIter);
                    System.out.flush();
                 }

                if (m_bWriteLog) {
                    try 
                    {
                        m_cBufferedWriter.write(Integer.toString(m_iIterations[i][j]));
                        m_cBufferedWriter.write(" ");
                    } 
                    catch (IOException ex) {
                        System.out.println("Error writing to file '" + m_sFileName + "'");
                    }
                }
            }
            if (m_bWriteLog) {
                try 
                {
                    m_cBufferedWriter.newLine();
                } 
                catch (IOException ex) {
                    System.out.println("Error writing to file '" + m_sFileName + "'");
                }
            }
        }
        m_dAbsSqValues = null;
        m_iIterations = null;
        cSum = null;
    }

    private void calcColour(int i, int j, int aIterations) 
    {
        Color cColour = Color.getHSBColor((int) Math.pow(aIterations, 4), 0xff,
                0xff * ((aIterations < MAXITER) ? 1 : 0));
        m_cCanvas.setPixelColour(i, j, cColour);
        cColour = null;
    }

    private void handleCalculation()
    {
        Complex cSummand = new Complex();

        for(int i = -800; i <= 800; i++)
        {
            for(int j = -800; j <= 800; j++)
            {
                cSummand.setRe(((double)i)/1000.0);
                cSummand.setIm(((double)j)/1000.0);
                this.setSummand(cSummand);
                this.calcAbsSqValues();
                this.getCanvas().paint(m_cCanvas.getGraphics());
                this.paint(this.getGraphics());
            }
        }
        cSummand = null;
        this.collectGarbage();
        System.gc();
        System.runFinalization();
    }

    public boolean isRunning() 
    {
        return m_bRunning;
    }

    public void setRunning(boolean aRunning) 
    {
        m_bRunning = aRunning;
    }

    public Canvas getCanvas()
    {
        return m_cCanvas;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        if(m_bRunning)
        {
            this.handleCalculation();
        }
    }
}

class JuliaCanvas extends Canvas 
{
    private int m_iWidth;
    private int m_iHeight;
    private Random m_cRnd;
    private BufferedImage m_cBackGroundImage = null;
    private int m_iRed[][];
    private int m_iGreen[][];
    private int m_iBlue[][];

    JuliaCanvas(int aWidth, int aHeight) 
    {
        m_iWidth = aWidth;
        m_iHeight = aHeight;
        m_cRnd = new Random();

        m_cRnd.setSeed(m_cRnd.nextLong());

        m_cBackGroundImage = new BufferedImage(m_iWidth, m_iHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

        m_iRed = new int[m_iHeight][m_iWidth];
        m_iGreen = new int[m_iHeight][m_iWidth];
        m_iBlue = new int[m_iHeight][m_iWidth];
    }

    public void init() {

    }

    public void setPixelColour(int i, int j, Color aColour) 
    {
        m_iRed[i][j] = aColour.getRed();
        m_iGreen[i][j] = aColour.getGreen();
        m_iBlue[i][j] = aColour.getBlue();
    }

    private int getRandomInt(double aProbability) 
    {
        return (m_cRnd.nextDouble() < aProbability) ? 1 : 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics aGraphics) 
    {
        // store on screen graphics
        Graphics cScreenGraphics = aGraphics;
        // render on background image
        aGraphics = m_cBackGroundImage.getGraphics();


        for (int i = 0; i < m_iWidth; i++) 
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < m_iHeight; j++) 
            {
                Color cColor = new Color(m_iRed[i][j], m_iGreen[i][j], m_iBlue[i][j]);
                aGraphics.setColor(cColor);
                aGraphics.drawRect(i, j, 0, 0);
                cColor = null;
            }
        }
        // rendering is done, draw background image to on screen graphics
        cScreenGraphics.drawImage(m_cBackGroundImage, 1, 1, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Graphics aGraphics) 
    {
        paint(aGraphics);
    }
}

class Complex {
    private double m_dRe;
    private double m_dIm;

    public Complex() 
    {
        m_dRe = 0;
        m_dIm = 0;
    }

    public Complex(double aRe, double aIm)
    {
        m_dRe = aRe;
        m_dIm = aIm;
    }

    public Complex(Complex aComplex)
    {
        m_dRe = aComplex.m_dRe;
        m_dIm = aComplex.m_dIm;
    }

    public double getRe() {
        return m_dRe;
    }

    public void setRe(double adRe)
    {
        m_dRe = adRe;
    }

    public double getIm() {
        return m_dIm;
    }

    public void setIm(double adIm)
    {
        m_dIm = adIm;
    }

    public void add(Complex acComplex) 
    {
         m_dRe += acComplex.getRe();
         m_dIm += acComplex.getIm();
    }

    public void square() 
    {
        double m_dReSave = m_dRe;
        m_dRe =  (m_dRe * m_dRe) - (m_dIm * m_dIm);
        m_dIm = 2 * m_dReSave * m_dIm;
    }

    public double getAbsSq()
    {
        return ((m_dRe * m_dRe) + (m_dIm * m_dIm));
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you give all parts of code? In this way it is not easy to see how your code is running.

Comment: @YusufK. because it's 545 lines of code... I can of course add the whole file if you wish

Comment: I think giving important parts may be useful. Creating Jframe and showing it, closing it. When you try close app? This part of codes make us help you.

Comment: @YusufK. Thank you, I added the whole files so I think you should be able to see all of that now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First;

Endless loop is not a proper way to do this. This part is loops and taking CPU and never give canvas to refresh screen. if you add below code your code will run as expected. but this is not the proper solution.

cMain.java:

```
while (true) {
    cJuliaSet.run();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Second: you could call run method when start button clicked. But you should create a thread in run method to not freeze screen.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
            int windowWidth = 1000;// (int)screenSize.getWidth() - 200;
            int windowHeight = 800;// (int)screenSize.getHeight() - 50;
            int plotWidth = 400;// (int)screenSize.getWidth() - 600;
            int plotHeight = 400;// (int)screenSize.getHeight() - 150;

            JuliaSet cJuliaSet = new JuliaSet("Julia Set", windowWidth, windowHeight, plotWidth, plotHeight);
            cJuliaSet.setVisible(true);
           //While loop removed
        }
```

actionPerformed:

```
if (strCmd.equals("Start")) {
            m_cCanvas.init();
            m_cSMsg = "c = " + Double.toString(m_dReal) + " + " + "j*" + Double.toString(m_dImag);
            m_bRunning = true;
            this.run();   // added call run method.
        } else if (aActionEvent.getSource() == m_cTReal) {
```

run method:

```
public void run()
    {
        if(m_bRunning)
        {
            new Thread(){ //Thread to release screen
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    JuliaSet.this.handleCalculation();
                }
            }.start(); //also thread must be started
        }
    }
```

As said by @RubioRic, SwingUtilities.invokeLater method is also a part of solution. But you need to check whole of your code and you should learn about Threads.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for such an extensive answer. That is exactly what I needed, and it works flawlessly. I will read up on threads a bit more, to be honest I have been putting it off for a bit and tried to work without them, but in this case it seems I didn't have any other chance. Thank you too, @RubioRic , both of your answers combined solved the problem. One thing is not clear to me though: how does `Thread()` know thanks to `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` that it should create a new object? Or am I wrong in thinking this?

Comment: @DavidWright You're welcome. Hmm, I think I don't understand the question. :) But I could say that Threat do not know creating a new object also do not create a new object. Only process forks to a new way.

Answer (score 2):

I'm quoting a recent comment from @MadProgrammer (including links)

*"Swing is single threaded, nothing you can do to change that, all events are posted to the event queue and processed by the Event Dispatching Thread, see [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details and have a look at [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for at least one possible solution"*

There is only one thread in your code. That thread is busy doing the calculation and can not respond to events located in the GUI. You have to separate the calculation in another thread that periodically updates the quantities that appears in the window. More info about that in the links, courtesy of @MadProgrammer, I insist.

UPDATED: As pointed by @Yusuf, the proper way of launching the JFrame is

```
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new JuliaSet("Julia Set", windowWidth, windowHeight, plotWidth, plotHeight);
        }
        });
```

Set the frame visible on construction and start calculation when the start button is pressed.